# Unable to Run ipython Notebook[Windows]

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am have been scratching my head for the last 4 hours but still I am unable to run ipython-notebook on windows

I have installed ipython using `pip install ipython[all]`

The ipython is running fine from cmd but when I start `ipython notebook`, Jupyter starts to run on `http://localhost:8888/tree` and there I am unable to start new notebook as the option is disabled

[image]

While I am facing these problem, the cmd is also reporting some messages having error code 404, Below is the screenshot of the cmd

i.e [image]

Comment: 'Notebooks' is not supposed to be a clickable item in the menu. It's a heading: click 'Python 2' to make a new Python 2 notebook. We do plan to improve that UI: https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/97

Comment: Thanks Thomas K for your help write an answer so that I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Notebooks' is not supposed to be a clickable item in the menu. It's a heading for the list of different kinds of notebook you can create. Click on 'Python 2' to create a Python 2 notebook, or any other entry you see below 'Notebooks' in the menu.

We have (in the development version) just changed the styling to try to make this more obvious:
https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/1180